# Problem HitTesting a geometry in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas, geometry

My WPF application has a canvas on which I draw tables and lines that connect them. When a user clicks on a table or line, I capture the MouseDown event of that control and do various stuff in the background. The problem is that while the tables are big, and so present no problems, the lines are only a couple of pixels thick, so clicking it's difficult and annoying 
because you need pinpoint precision.

My question is: is there a way to give a Geometry a bit of "margin" that is invisible but still captures clicks? (or any other solution that would work for what I'm trying to achieve, maybe there's a better approach, like hit-testing on the canvas maybe??).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, you can draw with transparent colors (with 0 for alpha channel). If you draw an extra wide line like this below the normal one, that will respond to hittests, even though it's invisible.

Comment: Thanks, thinking about it it was an obvious solution... I was thinking of how to extend the existing figure, never once considering just drawing another one under it :D